# how to implement algolia autocomplete on a single index, but i want results to show based on facets

Tags: search, autocomplete, full-text-search, algolia

I have an index on algolia, each document like this.

```
{
      "title": "sample title",
      "slug": "sample slug",
      "content": "Head towards Rajinder Da Dhaba for some insanely delicious Kebabs!!",
      "Tags": ["fashion", "shoes"],
      "created": "2017-03-30T12:10:08.815Z",
      "city": "delhi",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58b6f3ea884fdc682a820dad",
        "description": "Roughly, somewhere between insanity and zen. Mostly the guy at the window seat!",
        "displayName": "Jon Doe"
      },
      "type": "Post",
      "places": [
        {
          "name": "Rajinder Da Dhaba",
          "slug": "Rajinder-Da-Dhaba-safdarjung-9e9ffe",
          "location": {
            "_geoloc": [
              {
                "name": "Safdarjung",
                "_id": "59611a2c2094b56a39afcbce",
                "coordinates": {
                  "lng": 77.2030268,
                  "lat": 28.5685586
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "objectID": "58dcf5a0355b590560d6ad68",
}
```

I want to implement **autocomplete** on this.
However, when i see the demos present in algolia dashboard, i found out that it returns the complete documents.

I want to only match on user.displayName, place.name, and title

and return only these fields as suggestions in the autocomplete results instead of complete documents, which match.

I know I can create separate indexes for users, places;

But is this possible with only a single index??

Answer (score 0):

Did you had a look at http://algolia.com/doc/tutorials/search-ui/autocomplete/auto-complete/ ?

It shows how to have a custom display from an index.

To match on on user.displayName, place.name, and title
you can configure the "searchable attributes" from the algolia dashboard.

Comment: Yes i did that only. And it worked.
But due to some reasons, i have decided to go with separate indexes for autocomplete